# How can I fix element when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have a list in an HTML view.
What I want to do is fixing the header of the list when scrolling down. But that header should be hide when the list ended.
I have no idea how to fix that element in the list.
If I set the header position as fixed, it always fixed.
How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: can you show some code

Comment: <div className="col-lg-12">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-lg-3 tablet-hide"></div>
              {annualHeaderData.map( (item, idx) => <AnnualHeaderItem {...item} key={idx}/>)}
            </div>
          </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should set the header element's position attribute as sticky.
Here there are two important things when you use the sticky attribute.
You must also set position attributes. Something like this.

```
.list-header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 80px;
}
```

And the parent elements of the list header element should not have overflow:hidden property.

Please have a try and let me know if it works.

Thanks.

Comment: It works, well. But have a small problem. When I scroll down, it shows on the main nav bar. Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: You can set the nav bar's z-index attribute higher than the list header element's z-index value.